# Multiple Database Context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, architecture, unity-container, n-tier-architecture

I am following this [Contoso University MVC NTier University](http://contosontiermvc.codeplex.com/) architecture. But I don't know how to set it to multiple database context. In my MVC application, I have two database that I usually access.

- Project.Common (this is where put the common infrastructure like the IUnitOfWork, IRepository)
- Project.Data
- Project.Models
- Project.Service
- Project2.Data
- Project2.Models
- Project2.Service
- Project.Web

When I use the UnityContainer in Global.asax. I Register two Dbfactory and  Uow like :

```
IUnityContainer oContainer = new UnityContainer()
// ***** PROJECT *****
 .RegisterType<IProjectDBFactory, ProjectDBFactory>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IProjectDBFactory>())
 .RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, ProjectUow>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IUnitOfWork>())
 .RegisterType<IRepoPRJTABLE, RepoPRJTABLE>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IRepoPRJTABLE>())
 .RegisterType<IServiceRepository<PRJTABLE>, ServicePRJTABLE>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IServiceRepository<PRJTABLE>>())

 // ***** PROJECT2 *****
 .RegisterType<IProject2DBFactory, Project2WebDBFactory>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IProject2DBFactory>())
 .RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, Project2Uow>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IUnitOfWork>())
 .RegisterType<IRepoPRJ2TABLE, RepoPRJ2TABLE>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IRepoPRJ2TABLE>())
 .RegisterType<IServiceRepository<PRJ2TABLE>, ServicePRJ2TABLE>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IServiceRepository<PRJ2TABLE>>())
```

I can view the data perfectly. But when I look into the ServicePRJ, it's Unitofwork context is the for the PROJECT2. Please help me... I think I need to pass the context to the unitwork but I am having hard time constructing my code. I am new in coding with such architecture, new in using unitycontainer, new in mvc. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your second registration of **IUnitOfWork** for project 2 is overriding the first registration in the container.
You need to make specific unit of work interfaces for the respective projects.

```c#
interface IProjectUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork {}
interface IProject2UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork {}
....
IUnityContainer oContainer = new UnityContainer()
// ***** PROJECT *****
 .RegisterType<IProjectDBFactory, ProjectDBFactory>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IProjectDBFactory>())
 .RegisterType<IProjectUnitOfWork, ProjectUow>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IProjectUnitOfWork >())
 .RegisterType<IRepoPRJTABLE, RepoPRJTABLE>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IRepoPRJTABLE>())
 .RegisterType<IServiceRepository<PRJTABLE>, ServicePRJTABLE>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IServiceRepository<PRJTABLE>>())

 // ***** PROJECT2 *****
 .RegisterType<IProject2DBFactory, Project2WebDBFactory>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IProject2DBFactory>())
 .RegisterType<IProject2UnitOfWork, Project2Uow>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IProject2UnitOfWork >())
 .RegisterType<IRepoPRJ2TABLE, RepoPRJ2TABLE>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IRepoPRJ2TABLE>())
 .RegisterType<IServiceRepository<PRJ2TABLE>, ServicePRJ2TABLE>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IServiceRepository<PRJ2TABLE>>())
```